# finding a bug in a program

Tags: java, debugging

There is suppose to be some sort of fault before location A in the code below but I can't seem to figure it out. Does have something to do with the clone method? I just need help figuring where the error is and why then I can go about fixing it myself. Thank you.

```
class Vehicle implements Cloneable {

   private int x;

   public Vehicle(int y) { x = y;}

   public Object clone() { 
      Object result = new Vehicle(this.x);
      // Location "A"
      return result;
   }
   // other methods omitted
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {

   private int y;

   public Truck(int z) { super(z); y = z;}

   public Object clone() {
      Object result = super.clone();
      // Location "B"
      ((Truck) result).y = this.y;  // throws ClassCastException
      return result;             
   }
   // other methods omitted
}
```

Comment: I think you need to @Override the clone method as it comes  by default with the Object class, which every class is an extention of

Comment: In Truck's clone method, use `Truck result = super.clone();` and `result.y = y;`

Comment: @FredK `Truck result = super.clone();` and why should that be compilable?

Answer (score 0):

When `Truck.clone()` calls `super.clone()`, the returned value is a `Vehicle`, not a `Truck`.

Two options:

- Replace `super.clone()` with `new Truck(...)`
- Also use `super.clone()` in `Vehicle`, so the actual instance created is a `Truck`

I prefer second option:

```
class Vehicle implements Cloneable {

    private int x;

    public Vehicle(int y) { x = y;}

    @Override
    public Vehicle clone() { 
        try {
            return (Vehicle)super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // Cannot happen
        }
    }
}
class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private int y;

    public Truck(int z) { super(z); y = z;}

    @Override
    public Truck clone() {
        return (Truck)super.clone();
    }
}
```